# Border Width 100% of HTML + Responsive menu border & icon not correct

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

The first situation I have with my website is the border bottom of my navigation bar. I have tried changing the box-sizing to border-box but it still doesn't work. I want the border to be 100% width of the browser.

Second, I'm trying to create a responsive menu for both tablet and mobile changing my list items into a hamburger slider. Right now, it is awkward since my header image is floated left, and when i put in the hamburger menu, it does not jump below the logo even after i put clear both. Also, the border of the li is messed up, I want it to fill the width of the screen..

I have yet to put the javascript for the menu icon yet, I don't want to continue until I find a fix to these problems please help :(

html:

```
<header>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/brand.png" alt="George Designs Logo" class="brand"></a>

    <img src="images/menu.png" alt="menu" class="menu-trigger">
    <nav class="nav-menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The css is in the js fiddle

Here is the full project:
http://jsfiddle.net/ntnzz1fj/2/

Comment: `I want the border to be 100% width of the browser.` You just need `body {margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set some `margin`s which are unwanted on mobile or tablet deives.

You need to remove them for mobile devices in order to have a full width menu.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-menu {
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/7gvef594/)**

Also remove the browser default margin.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it looks exactly the way  Iwant it!

Answer (score 0):

As for making elements fit the whole width of the screen, this combination will ensure it's a block element.

```
.myElement {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Make to include margin: 0; on the body as well. I would recommend using Normalize.css before your main stylesheet. This normally prevents a lot of common kinks in styling.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Thanks for that, I will add that in!